# Typedef array weirdness

Tags: c, arrays

I've come across some code that I'd assumed was broken, but works due to something that I can't understand, or find explanation to. I'd be very grateful if someone could put me straight. It is demonstrated in the following snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char char_block[16];

void f(char_block *b) {
    printf("block 0x%p - b\n",   b);
    printf("block 0x%p - *b\n", *b);
}

main() {
    char_block b = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 };
    f(&b);
}
```

Compiled using g+ and executed, this prints:

```
block 0x0x7fff4794b4e0 - b
block 0x0x7fff4794b4e0 - *b
```

I had naively assumed that

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’

Would mean that the function would be equivilent to

```
void f(char ** b)
```

But something else is going on here?

Comment: The code does not implement a "*declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ ...*", but a "*declaration of a parameter as [pointer to] ‘‘array of type" ...*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `f()` the argument `b` has type `pointer to char_block` (pointer to array of 16 char); `*b` has type `char[16]`. In most contexts, usage of `*b` converts that type to a pointer to the array first element (of type `char*`).

*In some current C implementations values of type `char(*)[16]` and `char*` can safely be interpreted as `void*`, which is the type the format specifier in `%p` expects.*

Mind that the interpretation of `char(*)[16]` and `char*` as values of type `void*` is not guaranteed as successful by the Standard. You should cast the value to be safe

```
    printf("block 0x%p - b\n",   (void*)b); // b has type char(*)[16]
    printf("block 0x%p - *b\n", (void*)*b); // *b is converted to type char*
    sizeof *b == 16; // no conversion when used as argument to sizeof operator
```

Comment: that makes sense now - the dereferenced value has no choice but to decay back to a pointer. Very evil. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 6):

`char_block *` is `char (*)[16]`.